# Provides between the text content and my footer bar

Tags: html, css

I am going to make so that you can turn things up on the website like facebook, but this is how I have come into problems with my text content and my footer bar where it just gives some air in between these two.

**Html here:**

```
<div class="statusOpslag">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStatusTekst" CssClass="statusTekst" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                <div class="Statusfooter">
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSend" OnClick="ButtonSend_Click" runat="server" Text="Slå op" CssClass="statusKlikButtonOUT" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS here**

```
.statusOpslag {
   background: #ffffff;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 0;
   width: 95%;
}

.statusTekst {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   height: 120px;
   max-height: 120px;
   margin:0;
}

.Statusfooter {
   background: #F4F4F4;
   padding: 15px;
   margin:0px;
}

.statusKlikButtonOUT {
   background-color: #5cb85c;
   border: 0;
   color: green;  
}
```

You can see it problems here
[image]

**EIDT CSS**

I have done as you have described in your answer and it helps nothing. - sorry

```
   .statusOpslag {
   background: #ffffff;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0; 
}

.statusTekst {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   height: 120px;
   max-height: 120px;
   margin:0;
}

.Statusfooter {
   background: #F4F4F4;
   padding: 15px;
   margin:0px;
}

.statusKlikButtonOUT {
   background-color: #5cb85c;
   border: 0;
   color: green;  
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? If you feel like there is a gap, play with margins/paddings. Also, please provide generated HTML.

Comment: Remove the padding: 15px;

Comment: You could have edit the first css block, there is no need adding the same block again with couple of changes.

Comment: @shmnsw i have remove all padding and margin now. and its not work.

Comment: @shmnsw what you mean?

Comment: Checkout that textBox size, maybe you shoud resize it so it fit the bottom of the containing div

Comment: @shmnsw Do you have any suggestions on how I do it?

Comment: like people said here...set ".Statusfooter " to padding: 0 15px 0 15px; if you want to keep the padding to the left and the right but it's about it: http://jsfiddle.net/w99butew/

Comment: @Eran.E http://jsfiddle.net/w99butew/1/ I found out what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the margins you set. Then, add this in css:

```
*{
    margin: 0:
    padding: 0:
}
```

Once it's set, you don't need to set

```
margin: 0;
```

No where again.

Also, in your statusOpslog class you set margin twice:

```
margin: 10px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
```

You should only set it once.
If you do not want that margin you got in your question you should not set margin at all for that element.

Comment: i have fix its to `margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:0;`

Comment: You still have the margin: 10px, remove it

Comment: Remove the padding: 15px;